# qt creator needs a compiler set up to build. configure a compiler in the kit options, after adding compiler, cannot produce code for the qt version

Tags: qt

alright.. i downloaded and installed qt 5.1.1 (msvc2012, 64 bit) on my windows 7. i tried to run a simple qt gui application...  and this is what happened:

when i pressed "run"... there was error.. it said:

"qt creator needs a compiler set up to build. configure a compiler in the kit options"

then i found i had a list of 4 compilers to add from... when i added mingw... it said:

"the compiler mingw cannot produce codes for the qt version 'qt 5.1.1 MSVC2012 64 bit'"

it did the same for all the other compilers that i chose from the list of 4... nevertheless, i pressed "run" again.. as expected, it did not work... and this was the compile output:

```
19:16:31: Running steps for project code...
19:16:31: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64\bin\qmake.exe"              C:\Users\shades\code\code.pro -r -spec win32-g++
19:16:31: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
19:16:31: Starting: "mingw32-make.exe" -r -w 
qtcreator_ctrlc_stub: Command line failed: mingw32-make.exe -r -w 
19:16:32: The process "mingw32-make.exe" exited with code -1.
Error while building/deploying project code (kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.1 MSVC2012 64bit)
When executing step 'Make'
19:16:32: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

what do i do?? please please help....

Comment: You need to configure MSVC 2012 64bit as compiler, which requires to install Visual Studio 2012. That, or install Qt for mingw.

Comment: thanks for responding... how do i configure MSVC 2012 64bit as compiler???...(could you plz explain step by step, i dont really have much idea).... or where do i download qt for mingw from??... does that mean i have to download another huge  qt file??... what would that be like... 500 mb or something?!!.. but could you give me the link(to download qt for mingw) anyway...

Comment: You configure the compiler where you previously chose mingw. Of course, it requires a Visual Studio 2012 64 installation to be able to select the compiler there. Do you have that installed and working? The Qt for mingw installer is labeled "Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL, 666 MB)" on http://qt-project.org/downloads

Comment: no i dont... i have visual studio 2010... not 2012... so what do i do now... ?? download vs 2012 or qt for mingw??.. what's easier??

Answer (score 1):

The Qt version youh have is for use with the compiler MSVC2012 64 bit. That compiler is for Microsoft Visual C 2012 64 bit.

You should download the MinGW version if you want to use that compiler. The installer of the mingw version of Qt comes with the compilers for MinGW.

Comment: download all over again??!... 500 mb or something??... anyway... could you give me a link... thanks for helping..